# Hide Edit Profile & Settings for Community User on teams

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

Please hide the link to edit profile and settings for the community user on teams.  This user is "on the server farms" so there is no way to edit this user so we should hide this tab.  I know clicking on it yields a 404 but still:

[image]

Comment: SO should hire you as beta tester 

Comment: I wish i wish i wish

Comment: That dead link up there is rotting the hell out of people...

Comment: This seems buggy. :) Taking a look. Thanks @JonH!

Comment: Now, the link is still there, but you *can* edit Community. (although editing the user description doesn't cause any changes to be reflected on its page)