# There is an "Edit Profile & Settings" button on other profiles that doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am an admin on our team.

If I go to the profile page of another user I have the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab on top, clicking that leads me to https://stackoverflow.com/c/teamwork/users/edit/2, which is a 404:

[image]

This should either not be a 404, or the link shouldn't be there.

---

Bonus bug: my reputation is "0" on the 404 page?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369000/hide-edit-profile-settings-for-community-user-on-teams

Comment: Ah yeah, we should hide it for admins on all profiles. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be ready with our next release. Thank you for your report.